# regular expression generation

Tags: regex

I have to generate a regular expression to the check the first letter of any word for 'A','D'and 'E'.Word can be of any length.What should be the regular expression for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[ADE].*
```

Regular expressions, awesome!

EDIT: Case insensitive version.

```
^[ADEade].*
```